# Search for a pattern spanning multiple lines between 2 strings and does not include a different string, then replace with new value

Tags: bash, awk, sed

The title may be a bit vague, but I have a file that contains something like this

```
<Tag>
 <Tag 
    111
    222
 />
</Tag>
```

Using bash script (grep, sed, awk, etc.) I want to search for the inside tag and replace it with some new content

```
 <Tag>
     <Tag 
        333
        444
     />
    </Tag>
```

The new content can be all in one line, ie `<Tag 333 444 />`
I'm struggling with how to search for the inside Tag only, I can't find a way to extract a string starting with `<Tag` and end with `/>` but doesn't contain `>`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this, using GNU sed for `-E` and `-z`, isn't all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases you have that this doesn't work for:

```
$ sed -Ez 's:<Tag[^<>]+/>:<Tag 333 444 />:' file
<Tag>
 <Tag 333 444 />
</Tag>
```

Comment: That works exactly how I wanted. I had limited knowledge of bash and from what I read, sed only works for one line search, that's why I got stuck. I will need to study more. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
<Tag>
 <Tag 
    111
    222
 />
</Tag>
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{sub(/<Tag[^>]*\/>/,"<Tag 333 444 />")}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
<Tag>
 <Tag 333 444 />
</Tag>
```

Explanation: I set `RS` to empty line therefore inform GNU `AWK` that it should treat blank lines as separating rows. For given example file there is single row. Use [`sub` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to replace first occurence of `<Tag` followed by zero or more (`*`) non-`>` followed by `/>` (`/` must be escaped as it would otherwise terminate expression). using provided replacement. Independently of replacement taking place or not `print`. **Disclaimer**: I assume your file has never blank lines.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: If the input has more than 1 location to replace, then the ones from 2nd onwards get missed :  echo "${aaaa}${aaaa}" | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{sub(/<Tag[^>]*\/>/,"<Tag 333 444 />")}{print}'
<Tag>
 <Tag 333 444 />
</Tag><Tag>
 <Tag 
    111
    222
 />
</Tag>

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ?

```
 echo "${aaaa}" \
                 \
 | mawk 'BEGIN { RS=(ORS=_)"^$"
                 FS=(OFS="<Tag")"[^"(_="/>")"]+"_
                     OFS=(OFS)" 333 444 "_ } NF=NF'
<Tag>
 <Tag 333 444 />
</Tag>
```